# How to match a string with a wildcard character in java

Tags: java, regex

I need to write a regular expression that would match a string of value "*.log"
I have the following code and its doesnt seem to work as expected.

```
if (name.matches("\\*\\.log")
```

The above statement returns false, when the value of name is "*.log"

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: the regex is correct, from what I can read from your question, there's no reason for the regex to fail.

Comment: I just ran this and it outputted true. So I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: Your code is equivalent of `if (name.equals("*.log")`. It should be working fine.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you doing that? Couldn't you just do

```
if(name.endsWith(".log"))
```

It seems to me like that would be a simpler option, since anything can be before .log, just like if you used a wildcard.
Also, if you want to make sure that it isn't just ".log", that is also very simple.

```
if(name.endsWith(".log") && !name.equals(".log"))
```

Hopefully I helped a bit!

Answer (score 1):

I think this regular expression will helpful to you......

```
^\*\.log$
```

For php,

```
$re = "/\\*\\.log/"; 
$str = "*.log"; 

preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
```

For JavaScript,

```
var re = /\*\.log/; 
var str = '*.log';
var m;

if ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }
    // View your result using the m-variable.
    // eg m[0] etc.
}
```

For Python,

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'\*\.log')
test_str = u"*.log"

re.search(p, test_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

As simple as:

```
\*\.log
```

You can always check here:

https://www.regex101.com/r/vK7mQ6/2

Comment: And now we are back to regex which OP is already using since string `"\\*\\.log"` represents `\*\.log`. If I ware you I would temporary remove this answer and undelete with new informations *after* OP provides more informations which will allows us to reproduce described problem. For now your answer looks like ["works for me" comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118992/are-works-for-me-answers-valid).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code :

```
String name="test.log";
if (name.matches("^.+\\.log$") ) {
    System.out.println("Okay");
}
```